# screen reload based on condition - android

Tags: android, screen, reload

```
package com.Example.Company;

public class MultipleViewsLayered extends GraphicsActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public int myCounter;
    public boolean oneDone;
    public boolean twoDone;
    public boolean threeDone;
    public boolean fourDone;
    public boolean ScreenCompleted; 
    public ImageView iv3;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.MultipleViewsLayered);

        // Grabbing the Application context         
        final Context context = getApplication();                   
        // Creating a new LinearLayout  add the linear definition again.       
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);                   
        // Setting the orientation to vertical         
        ////relativeLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);                   

        // Creating Fish

        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);         
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish2);
        // relative layout parameters
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);        
        //iv.setId(1);                          
        relativeLayout.addView(iv,lp);        

        // Creating transparent image with numbers.
        final ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ctdsquareone);
        //iv2.setId(2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.addView(iv2,lp2);                    

        final CustomViewCanvas myCanvas = new CustomViewCanvas(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.addView(myCanvas,lp3);

        setContentView(relativeLayout);              

     // Get the app's shared preferences        
        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();       
        myCounter = app_preferences.getInt("myCounter", 0);     
        // Increment the counter                       
        editor.putInt("myCounter", ++myCounter);        
        editor.commit(); 

        oneDone = false;
        twoDone = false;
        threeDone = false;
        fourDone = false;
        ScreenCompleted = false;

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);       

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);    

    } 

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;


    public class CustomViewCanvas extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();      

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        private Path mPath;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;


        public CustomViewCanvas (Context context){
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            //New Bitmap empty
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);           
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            //Path
            mPath = new Path();                                                 

        }        

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                        
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);


            //Path
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);            

        }

        //
         private float mX, mY;
            private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

            private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
            private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
                float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;

            //*************************************************************************

            // HERE IS THE ISSUE
            // I WANT TO CHANGE the IV IMAGE HERE WHEN ScreenCompleted IS TRUE.
            // IT WILL BE SET TO TRUE HERE WHEN A LINE IS COMPLETED.

            //*************************************************************************


                }              
            }

            private void touch_up() {
                mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                // commit the path to our offscreen            
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);                
                // kill this so we don't double draw
                mPath.reset();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        touch_start(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        touch_move(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        touch_up();
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }       
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: Oh, it was hidden in the code. Very subtle.

Comment: what are the conditions?  why repaint the entire screen and not just change the image?

Comment: Changing the image is what I am trying to do. If I can do that I don't have to reload the view. The condition is a boolean turning from true to false.

Comment: What exacly is the edit from MByD? It says edited by MByD 6 minutes ago but not clear what the edit is? Never mind, got it...click the link next to edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

after reading the comment "*Changing the image is what I am trying to do. If I can do that I don't have to reload the view. The condition is a boolean turning from true to false*", I guess what you need is just a way to reference a widget from other class. Then, just changing the image by using a new `setImageResource (RID);` should be enough to refresh the screen with the new image. Here is a complete example of it. There's a class that upon clicking on a button, checks whether a checkbox is checked or not. If it is, then it will change the image:

**ListViewTest.java**

```
package com.aleadam.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ListViewTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        MyLayout myl = new MyLayout (this);
        myl.setImage(img);
        ll.addView(img, lp);
        ll.addView(myl, lp);
        setContentView (ll);
    }
}
```

**MyLayout.java**

```
package com.aleadam.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView img;
    private Button btn;
    private CheckBox chkbox;
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super (context);
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        btn = new Button (context);
        chkbox = new CheckBox (context);
        btn.setText("Click");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
        chkbox.setText("Select");
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.addView(btn, lp);
        this.addView(chkbox,lp);
    }
    public void setImage (ImageView view) {
        this.img = view;
    }
    private class MyListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (chkbox.isChecked()) {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If your Class2 object is visible on the screen, try `this.getRootView().invalidate();`

From the View reference page:

> Drawing
>
> Drawing is handled by walking the tree and rendering each view that intersects the the invalid region. Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will draw before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree. If you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw it for you before calling back to its onDraw() method.
>
> Note that the framework will not draw views that are not in the invalid region.
>
> To force a view to draw, call invalidate().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Aleadam, I have gone through the doc a few times trying to find the solution. Invalidating the parent view with this.getRootView().invalidate() was my first attempt. It doesn't work.

Comment: This commnets is coming in two parts, too long... Aleadam, I see one difference in our codes. For the seconed object I do Class2 extends View and you do class MyLayout extends LinearLayout. In my class if I do this.addview I get an error. Am I correct that since I am in a view and not a layout I can't additem? Is this the error? How do I reference the relative layout from Class2, or it is just that I can't becasue I am extending a view? I hope I am not confusing you more with my comments.

Comment: Meanwhile I will test if I can change my Class2 to extend a layout add my view in there (canvas), add another button, so I can have a listener and when the button is clicked the image iv will change. For the buttom I am going to try and invoke the onclick event when the boolean value changes and eventually make it invisible.

Comment: As soon as I get 2 more reputations I will vote you up. Btw, I appreciate you stopping by and naswering questions. I really like it here.

Comment: @George yes, `addView(...)` is not a method from `View` class, but from `ViewGroup`, off which `LinearLayout` is a subclass. If you are adding more than one widget to your class, then it makes more sense to extend any `ViewGroup` subclass (I just chose `LinearLayout` fot its simplicity). You should be now on track to get your class working. Good luck!

Comment: I changed my class to a relative layout and now my canvas is not working. I added the checkbox and it is the only one that I can click. I can no longer paint on the canvas. Back to the drawing board and the books...

Comment: Add your Class extending View to a Layout. I extended the layout only to show you an example. The key part of my code is to maintain a reference to the ImageView you want to change. The rest is all accessory.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the entire thing. I got all my events to work in order and just as I described. I have the two images and the idden check box and the canvas on top. Thanks everyone for their help. I learn more on this every day.